# Is it possible integrate Push notification with only AWS ( Without Firebase) and how can i integrate this?

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, amazon-sns

I want to integrate Flutter push notification using AWS, when i try to search resources, I found if I use AWS SNS Firebase is required, How can I solve this without firebase?

I try from this url: [Flutter AWS SNS](https://medium.com/iiitians-network/flutter-push-notifications-using-aws-sns-dac464c1edf0)

here use Firebase, is it possible to resolve this issue without firebase?

Comment: No, the platform-specific transport service is needed to deliver a message to a device: FCM for Android and APNs for iOS.